# I can't understand why CSS Transition is not working on keydown

Tags: javascript, css, transition, keydown

I'm trying to make animation for moving block to the right and to the left. But I can't understand why it's not working. For example, it works well for on click event. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/YaroslavTER/pen/qBdMWgm).
Thanks

```js
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function({
  keyCode,
  which
}) {
  const keycode = keyCode ? keyCode : which;
  switch (keycode) {
    case (39):
      box.classList.add('move-right');
      box.classList.remove('move-left');
      break;
    case (37):
      box.classList.add('move-left');
      box.classList.remove('move-right');
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
  transition: margin-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
}

.move-right {
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.move-left {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Use `transition: margin 0.5s ...;`

Comment: it will work for `margin-left`, I just meant to have for `margin` instead of adding all margin attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two instances of `transition` in your cssCSS

```css
.box {
  ...
  transition: margin-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
  transition: margin-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
}
```

If you want to specifically have different transitions between margin-left and margin-top, you can combine them.

```css
.box {
  ...
  transition: margin-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1), margin-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

transition should be added once, here is a working snippet:

```js
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];

document.addEventListener('keydown', function({keyCode, which}) {
  const keycode = keyCode ? keyCode : which;
  switch(keycode) {
    case(39):
      box.classList.add('move-right');
      box.classList.remove('move-left');
      break;
    case(37):
      box.classList.add('move-left');
      box.classList.remove('move-right');
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: margin 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
}

.move-right {
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.move-left {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `css` that you have written,

```
.box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
  transition: margin-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
}
```

You have 2 transition properties in place, and the transition property get overridden by the next one, which transitions `margin-top` property.

When the styles are computed the this is what the css rule looks like.

```
.box {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, .7, 0, 1);
}
```

As you have keys with the same type, the last rule wins, in this transition for `margin-top` and the transition for `margin-left` is lost.

So either remove the 2nd transition rule or write it as a single rule, will comma separated properties.